# HttpClient: This instance has already started one or more requests. Properties can only be modified before sending the first request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, dotnet-httpclient, ihttpclientfactory

I have an ASP.NET MVC application which invokes an ASP.NET Web API REST Service each time a button is pressed in the UI.

Each time this button is pressed below `DumpWarehouseDataIntoFile` method is executed.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public async Task DumpWarehouseDataIntoFile(Warehouse myData, string path, string filename)
    { 
        try
        {
           //Hosted web API REST Service base url  
           string Baseurl = "http://XXX.XXX.XX.X:YYYY/";  

           //using (var client = new HttpClient())  --> I have declared client as an static variable
           //{  
            //Passing service base url  
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);  

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();  

            //Define request data format  
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));  
              
            // Serialize parameter to pass to the asp web api rest service
            string jsonParam = Newtonsoft.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myData);

            //Sending request to find web api REST service resource  using HttpClient
            var httpContent = new StringContent(jsonParam, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.PostAsync("api/Warehouse/DumpIntoFile", httpContent);  

            //Checking the response is successful or not which is sent using HttpClient  
            if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)  
            {  
               // Some other sftuff here
            }
           //}
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
              // Do some stuff here
         } // End Try

    } // End DumpWarehouseDataIntoFile method
} // End class
```

`Warehouse` class object:

```
public class Warehouse
{
    public DataTable dt { get; set; }
    public string Filepath { get; set; }
}
```

I have found in [this post](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) that pattern:

```
using (var myClient = new HttpClient())
{
}
```

is not recommended to be used since it leads to socket exhaustion (`System.Net.Sockets.SocketException`). There it is recommended to use `HttpClient` as static variable and reuse it as it helps to reduce waste of sockets. So I have used a static variable.

The problem with this approach (in my scenario) is that it only works first button is pressed, next times  button is pressed and `DumpWarehouseDataIntoFile` method is executed, below exception is thrown:

> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> `System.InvalidOperationException`: This instance has already started
> one or more requests. Properties can only be modified before sending
> the first request.

As error says, properties like base address, etc. can only be modified once before sending the first request.

I have googled and found some solutions proposed:

### First solution

So it seems like singleton pattern would be a good option, as proposed [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/330364/should-we-create-a-new-single-instance-of-httpclient-for-all-requests). Below the singleton proposed by Alper:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
//You need to install package Newtonsoft.Json > https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

public class MyApiClient : IDisposable
{
    private readonly TimeSpan _timeout;
    private HttpClient _httpClient;
    private HttpClientHandler _httpClientHandler;
    private readonly string _baseUrl;
    private const string ClientUserAgent = "my-api-client-v1";
    private const string MediaTypeJson = "application/json";

    public MyApiClient(string baseUrl, TimeSpan? timeout = null)
    {
        _baseUrl = NormalizeBaseUrl(baseUrl);
        _timeout = timeout ?? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90);    
    }

    public async Task<string> PostAsync(string url, object input)
    {
        EnsureHttpClientCreated();

        using (var requestContent = new StringContent(ConvertToJsonString(input), Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeJson))
        {
            using (var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(url, requestContent))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task<TResult> PostAsync<TResult>(string url, object input) where TResult : class, new()
    {
        var strResponse = await PostAsync(url, input);

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(strResponse, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        });
    }

    public async Task<TResult> GetAsync<TResult>(string url) where TResult : class, new()
    {
        var strResponse = await GetAsync(url);

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(strResponse, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        });
    }

    public async Task<string> GetAsync(string url)
    {
        EnsureHttpClientCreated();

        using (var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }

    public async Task<string> PutAsync(string url, object input)
    {
        return await PutAsync(url, new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input), Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeJson));
    }

    public async Task<string> PutAsync(string url, HttpContent content)
    {
        EnsureHttpClientCreated();

        using (var response = await _httpClient.PutAsync(url, content))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }

    public async Task<string> DeleteAsync(string url)
    {
        EnsureHttpClientCreated();

        using (var response = await _httpClient.DeleteAsync(url))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _httpClientHandler?.Dispose();
        _httpClient?.Dispose();
    }

    private void CreateHttpClient()
    {
        _httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip
        };

        _httpClient = new HttpClient(_httpClientHandler, false)
        {
            Timeout = _timeout
        };

        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd(ClientUserAgent);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_baseUrl))
        {
            _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_baseUrl);
        }

        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(MediaTypeJson));
    }

    private void EnsureHttpClientCreated()
    {
        if (_httpClient == null)
        {
            CreateHttpClient();
        }
    }

    private static string ConvertToJsonString(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        });
    }

    private static string NormalizeBaseUrl(string url)
    {
        return url.EndsWith("/") ? url : url + "/";
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
using (var client = new MyApiClient("http://localhost:8080"))
{
    var response = client.GetAsync("api/users/findByUsername?username=alper").Result;
    var userResponse = client.GetAsync<MyUser>("api/users/findByUsername?username=alper").Result;
}
```

The problem I see here is that if you call above code many times (in my case would be each time I press the button on the UI and I call `DumpWarehouseDataIntoFile` method), you create and instance of `MyApiClient` each time and therefore a new instance of `HttpClient` is created and I want to reuse `HttpClient`, not to make many instances of it.

### Second solution

Creating a kind of factory as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235677/httpclient-this-instance-has-already-started) by Nico. Below the code he proposes:

```
public interface IHttpClientFactory
{
    HttpClient CreateClient();
}

public class HttpClientFactory : IHttpClientFactory
{
    static string baseAddress = "http://example.com";

    public HttpClient CreateClient()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        SetupClientDefaults(client);
        return client;
    }

    protected virtual void SetupClientDefaults(HttpClient client)
    {
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30); //set your own timeout.
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
public HomeController(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
{
    _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
}

readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

public IActionResult Index()
{
    var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    //....do your code
    return View();
}
```

Here again you create a new instance of `HttpClient` each time you call `CreateClient`. You do not reuse `HttpClient` object.

### Third Solution

Making HTTP requests using `IHttpClientFactory` as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0).
The problem is that it is only available for .NET Core, not standard ASP.NET Framework, though it seems it is available by installing [this nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/). It seems like it automatically manages efficiently `HttpClient` instances and I would like to apply it to my scenario. I want to avoid to
reinvent the wheel.

I have never used `IHttpClientFactory` and I have no idea on how to use it: configure some features like base address, set request headers, create an instance of `HttpClient` and then invoke `PostAsync` on it passing as parameter the `HttpContent`.

I think this is the best approach so could someone tell me the necessary steps I need to do in order to make the same things I do in `DumpWarehouseDataIntoFile` method but using `IHttpClientFactory`? I am a bit lost, I do not know how to apply `IHttpClientFactory` to do the same as I do within `DumpWarehouseDataIntoFile` method.

Any others solutions not proposed here and also some code snippets will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

#### `HttpClient`

The HttpClient can throw `InvalidOperationException` in the following cases:

- When the `BaseAddress` setter is called after a request has been sent out
- When the `Timeout` setter is called after a request has been sent out
- When the `MaxResponseContentBufferSize` setter is called after a request has been sent out
- When an operation has already started and resend was requested

In order to avoid these you can set the first two on per request level, for example:

```cs
CancellationTokenSource timeoutSource = new CancellationTokenSource(2000);
await httpClient.GetAsync("http://www.foo.bar", timeoutSource.Token);
```

#### `HttpClientFactory`

You can use the IHttpClientFactory in .NET Framework with the [following trick](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/843):

- `AddHttpClient` [registers](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L37) the `DefaultHttpClientFactory` for `IHttpClientFactory`
- Then you can retrieve it from the DI container

```cs
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection().AddHttpClient().BuildServiceProvider();
container.RegisterInstance(serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>());
container.ContainerScope.RegisterForDisposal(serviceProvider);
```

This sample uses `SimpleInjector` but the same concept can be applied for any other DI framework.

Answer (score 1):

Better to add the request url and the headers at the message. Don't use `httpClient.BaseAddress` or `httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders` unless you have a default requirement.

```
HttpRequestMessage msg = new HttpRequestMessage {
    Method = HttpMethod.Put,
    RequestUri = new Uri(url),
    Headers = httpRequestHeaders;
};

httpClient.SendAsync(msg);
```

It works well for reusing the `HttpClient` for many requests

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but will what happen if you move this lines to constructor:

```
        //Passing service base url  
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);  

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();  

        //Define request data format  
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept
       .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

I think that re-initialization is problem.